# How to speed up reading DBF file to Dataframe in PYTHON?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, vectorization, dbf

I am reading .dbf files into a dataframe using the following routine dbf2DF (https://gist.github.com/ryan-hill/f90b1c68f60d12baea81).

```
import pysal as ps
import pandas as pd
'''
Arguments
---------
dbfile  : DBF file - Input to be imported
upper   : Condition - If true, make column heads upper case
'''

    def dbf2DF(dbfile, upper=True): #Reads in DBF files and returns Pandas DF
        db = ps.open(dbfile) #Pysal to open DBF
        d = {col: db.by_col(col) for col in db.header} #Convert dbf to dictionary
        #pandasDF = pd.DataFrame(db[:]) #Convert to Pandas DF
        pandasDF = pd.DataFrame(d) #Convert to Pandas DF
        if upper == True: #Make columns uppercase if wanted 
            pandasDF.columns = map(str.upper, db.header) 
        db.close() 
        return pandasDF
```

Whilst it does what I want, it is slow - taking 56s for 1.7m records.

Of that, it takes 54s to process the following line:

```
d = {col: db.by_col(col) for col in db.header} #Convert dbf to dictionary
```

My question is - can we speed up this line by eliminating the 'for' loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't mention how many columns are in your file.  That can have a significant impact on how long the following takes.  The code below takes about 70 seconds on 1.3 million records with 33 columns.  However, when the number of columns is reduced to 10, the time it takes is ~25 seconds.

This code does not take into account memo fields.

I am using [Ethan Furman's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/208880/ethan-furman) .dbf library https://pypi.org/project/dbf/

A .dbf file is a fixed width format file with a bit of metadata describing the columns, record counts, etc...

Pandas has a [read_fwf](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) function that you can use to read the data portion of the .dbf file, passing along the column widths and names.

```
import io
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import regex
import dbf

def format_dates(df, columns):
    if columns:
        df[columns] = df[columns].astype(np.datetime64, errors='ignore')

def format_float(df, columns):
    if columns:
        df[columns] = df[columns].astype(np.float64, errors='ignore')

def format_int(df, columns):
    if columns:
        df[columns] = df[columns].astype(np.int64, errors='ignore')

def format_bool(df, columns):
    if columns:
        df[columns] = df[columns].apply(lambda x: np.where(x == 'T', True, False))

def get_dbf_field_meta(table, keep_delete_mark=False):
    column_names = []
    field_types = defaultdict(list)
    field_sizes = []
    if keep_delete_mark:
        column_names.append('dbf_delete')
        field_sizes.append(1)
    column_names.extend(table.field_names)
    for field in table.field_names:
        fld_info = table.field_info(field)
        field_sizes.append(fld_info[1])
        ftype = fld_info[3]
        if ftype == 'default':
            ftype = ['float', 'int'][fld_info[0] == '78']
        field_types[ftype].append(field)

    return column_names, field_types, field_sizes

def get_fwf_dataframe_from_dbf(table_name):
    with dbf.Table(table_name).open(dbf.READ_ONLY) as table:
        column_names, field_types, field_sizes = get_dbf_field_meta(table, keep_delete_mark=True)

        # how far to read .dbf file to reach data
        skip_meta = len(table._meta.header._data)
        data = table._meta.dfd.read()[skip_meta:-1].decode('cp1252')

        chunk_size = min(20000 * table.record_length, len(data))
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)
        while data:
            chunk, data = data[:chunk_size], data[chunk_size:]
            chunk = '\n'.join(regex.findall(f'.{{{table.record_length}}}', chunk)) + '\n'
            iodata = io.StringIO(chunk)
            incoming = pd.read_fwf(iodata, widths=field_sizes, names=column_names, header=None, keep_default_na=False, dtype=object, index_col=False)
            df = pd.concat([df, incoming])
            del iodata, incoming

        # typecast columns
        format_dates(df, field_types.get(datetime.date, []))
        format_float(df, field_types.get('float', []))
        format_int(df, field_types.get('int', []))
        format_bool(df, field_types.get(bool, []))
    return df

if __name__ == '__main__':
    table_name = r"<your table>"
    df = get_fwf_dataframe_from_dbf(table_name)
```

Comment: Some numeric fields are stored as text (Numeric, Float), while others are stored as binary (Double, Integer) -- does this work with both types?

Comment: I did not take binary fields into account here.  My specific needs have not required them.  I will take a closer look at those when I have sufficient time.

Comment: Nick, Thank you for your suggestion. I tried the code you supplied, and it took 97.7s to read the same .dbf file (in Vessel Traffic Data December 2020 @ https://www.operations.amsa.gov.au/Spatial/DataServices/DigitalData). FYI, this is made up of 1758205 rows × 12 columns (mostly floats)). You may also be interested to know that, (of the 97.7s) it took 90.1s for the while loop in get_fwf_dataframe_from_dbf! This harks back to my question about seeking alternatives to looping structures.

Comment: I removed the chunking and just read the entire data and tested the time on each part.  What I found out is that the pandas.read_fwf is what takes the most time.   However, removing the chunking and reading the data directly into StringIO did shave off more than 5 seconds on my 10 column table.   The chunking was necessary when I was using 32-bit Python due to memory constraints.

Comment: Nick, I've now found the simpledbf library (https://pypi.org/project/simpledbf/). By using this, I can read the .dbf data into the df in 41.6s! That's probably as good as I'm going to get. Thank you for your help.